# Basic probability oak and pine question

Tags: probability

The probability that an oak log is split on any chop is $1/3$ and the probability that a pine log is split on any chop is $2/3$. In a large batch of logs, three quarters of the logs are oak and the rest are pine. The random variable $Y$ is the number of chops required to split a log chosen at random from this batch. How to find ${P}(Y=r)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you write what your thoughts are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P(Y=r)=\left(\frac34\cdot\left(1-\frac13\right)^{r-1}\cdot\frac13\right)+\left(\frac14\cdot\left(1-\frac23\right)^{r-1}\cdot\frac23\right)$$